# Convertir radianes a grados

Tags: javascript, matemáticas

Estoy realizando un cálculo para obtener un valor en grados, pero me he topado con que el resultado de una operación en *JavaScript*, donde intervengan los tipos de operaciones trigonométricas, arroja dichos valores en radianes.

#### Formula

```
23.45 * sin(360 * ((284 + dn)/365))
```

Entonces realizo en *JavaScript* de la siguiente manera:

```js
var miVariable = 23.45 * Math.sin(360 * ((284 + 196)/365));
console.log(miVariable);
```

El valor arrojado es **19.15**, claro, redondeando el valor final.

El problema, es que *JavaScript* da el resultado en radianes, y lo quiero en grados. Busqué, y la solución que dan es, multiplicar el resultado en radianes de la siguiente manera:

```
miVariable * (180/Math.PI);
```

... pero el valor arrojado es **1097.2141776755263**

De igual forma, si multiplico el resultado pero solo del cálculo de la operación del *seno*, entra dentro de un rango posible de ángulo entre **-360** y **360**.

```js
var valorSeno = Math.sin(360 * ((284 + 196)/365));
var valorFinal = valorSeno * (180/Math.PI);
console.log(valorFinal);
```

De igual forma, aquí aún no multiplico por el valor **23.45**, ya que arroja, el mismo valor al final.

El valor final que necesito es **21.51**

Comment: Por qué divides por 365?

Comment: @Alfabravo https://image.slidesharecdn.com/conferenciarelojesdesolluishtriana-100630104936-phpapp02/95/conferencia-relojes-de-sol-luis-h-triana-12-728.jpg?cb=1277895918

Comment: Aaahhhh, la fórmula de la declinación redondea en 365. Súper que además ya hubo una respuesta acertada. Gracias por el link a la imagen!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hay que jugar un poco con las convenciones para mantener todas las equivalencias.

Bien sabes que la función de [Math.sin(x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/seno) recibe sus parámetros como radianes. **El resultado sigue en radianes**.

De ahí aplica el álgebra de la escuela para resolver el seno y dar una última conversión para obtener los grados.

```js
Math.grados = function(radianes) {
  return radianes * 180 / Math.PI;
};

Math.radianes = function(grados) {
  return grados * Math.PI / 180;
};

let antesSeno = Math.radianes(360 * ((284 + 196)/365)),
  miVariable = 23.45 * Math.sin(antesSeno),
  miGrados = Math.grados(miVariable);
console.log(antesSeno);
console.log(miVariable);
console.log(miGrados);
```

Comment: Cuando haces `let antesSeno...`, por qué divides entre 365? Suena a error, jejeje. Saludos y buena respuesta

Comment: Porque es la forma que usa el OP

Answer (score 5):

Se puede obtener el resultado en grados, sin hacer la conversión de radianes a grados. En vez de eso, decidí hacer un pequeño cambio en la fórmula matemática.

La fórmula original es esta:

```
23.45 * sin(360 * ((284 + dn)/365))
```

Solo cambié el `360` por el doble de pi (`2*Math.PI`). Aparentemente, 180º es la equivalencia de pi.

He programado la función para que se adapte a la cantidad de días que tenga el año, es decir, si es bisiesto o no.

```js
var dn = 196
var declinación = (dn,días)=>23.45*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*(284+dn)/días)

function formatear(i,días)
{
  var dec = declinación(i,días)
  var signo = 2*+(dec>=0)-1
  var dec_abs = Math.abs(dec)
  var grados = Math.floor(dec_abs)
  var minutos = Math.floor((dec_abs-grados)*60)
  var segundos = Math.floor(((dec_abs-grados)*60-minutos)*60)
  return i+" "+días+"\t"+grados*signo+"º\t"+minutos+"'\t"+segundos+"''\t"+dec+"\n"
}

console.log(formatear(dn,365))
console.log(formatear(dn,366))

var salida=""
for(var i=1;i<=366;i++)
{
  if(i!=366){salida+=formatear(i,365)}
  salida+=formatear(i,366)
}
console.log(salida)
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta maestro, usted es bueno con los números.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la fórmula para convertir esto está mal y debe ser de esta forma:

```
const dregreesToRadian = deg => deg * Math.PI / 180;
```

Comment: si eso probé, pero es al contrario lo que necesito.

Comment: Bueno, si crees que está mal, podrías explicarnos por qué... y de paso explicarnos por qué debe ser de la forma que mencionas...

Answer (score 0):

Esta fórmula te aseguro que funciona: `var grados = radianes * (180 / Math.PI);`