# ¿Cómo puedo incluir un código de JavaScript dentro de un HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría crear un conversor de grados a radianes en HTML, entonces quiero incluir el script de esta publicación: [Convertir radianes a grados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161094/convertir-radianes-a-grados/161102)
dentro de un HTML para poder subirlo a una web. Pero, no sé cómo añadirlo, ¿pueden ayudarme con este proyecto?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La etiqueta `script` sirve para poder agregar código JavaScript en el HTML. El código puede ir dentro de la etiqueta o se le puede pasar una ruta relativa (o absoluta) archivo `.js` que contiene el código.

**Dentro de la etiqueta**

```js
<script>
alert('Hola, soy JS')
</script>
```

**Enlazando el archivo**

```js
<script src="ruta/archivo.js"></script>
```

Luego de esto, no hay otra forma de incluir JS en el HTML que yo sepa.

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola Oriol, bienvenido!
Solamente tienes que insertar

```
<script src="archivo.js"></script>
```

abajo de todo del `<body>`

Asegúrate de tener bien la ruta del archivo js ahí donde pone src="".

Comment: Entonces, ¿añadiendo esto ya se generará el diseño? Quiero decir la distribución de los botones de la calculadora: valor de entrada, resultado y botón de calcular.

Comment: @Oriol, no, la respuesta es solo para agregar el _script_, tú ya debes tener todos los elementos en HTML y aplicar estilos (diseño) con CSS.