# Mi código Javascript no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

He seguido esta pregunta sobre HTML y Javascript: [Convertir radianes a grados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161094/convertir-radianes-a-grados/)

He estado probando y buscando ejemplos de Internet y al final he creado un código por mi cuenta, pero no acaba de funcionar.

Lo adjunto a continuación por si alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo:

```html
<title>Conversor de grados a radianes</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

Math.grados = function(radianes) {
  return radianes * 180 / Math.PI;
};

Math.radianes = function(grados) {
  return grados * Math.PI / 180;
};

function formulario_calculadora(){
Radianes = document.f1.radianes.value
Grados = document.f1.grados.value
if (Grados == null) {
resultado = function(radianes)
else {
resultado = function(grados)
}
}
document.f1.res.value = resultado
}

</script>



<form name="f1">Grados: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="grados"> <br>Radianes: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="radianes"> <br><br><input onclick="calculadora_grados_radianes()" type="button" value="Convertir"> 
<br><br>Resultado : <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="res"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Sé más específico: _¿qué no funciona?_ Recordá que [es.so] no es un servicio de depuración de código; además, aquella pregunta también terminó cerrada ya que tampoco has dado más detalles. Leé [ask].

Comment: Por otra parte, estás mencionando la pregunta de otro usuario... ¿En realidad quisiste decir que _te basaste en esa pregunta_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema principal que sufres te está apareciendo en la consola de depuración de Javascript cuando cargas la página:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'

Es debido a que no has estructurado adecuadamente los bloques de código correspondientes al "if" y su "else".

Además, aunque no te salga ese error, no estás llamando a la función adecuada en el evento "onclick" del botón:

```
<input onclick="calculadora_grados_radianes()" type="button" value="Convertir">
```

Si te das cuenta, tu función se llama `formulario_calculadora()` y no `calculadora_grados_radianes()`.

Seguimos con la definición de tus funciones, en las que intentas definir nueva funcionalidad de una clase que ya existe (`Math`), algo que está completamente desaconsejado. Es mejor tener tus propias funciones y clases.

Además, las estás llamando usando el nombre de función `function` como en este trozo:

```
resultado = function(radianes)
```

Cuando deberías haberla llamado usando el nombre con el que la has definido, `Math.grados`.

Por último, las variables que usas para obtener los grados y radianes llevan una letra mayúscula que luego no usas al pasar como parámetro los valores.

Éste podría ser tu código corregido:

```html
<title>Conversor de grados a radianes</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

class Mates {
  static grados(radianes) {
    return radianes * 180 / Math.PI;
  }
  static radianes(grados) {
    return grados * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}

function formulario_calculadora() {
  /* Convertimos los campos de texto en datos de coma flotante */
  const radianes = parseFloat(document.f1.radianes.value);
  const grados = parseFloat(document.f1.grados.value);
  if (isNaN(radianes) === false) {
    /* Si radianes es correcto */
    resultado = Mates.grados(radianes);
  } else if (isNaN(grados) === false) {
    /* Si grados es correcto */
    resultado = Mates.radianes(grados);
  } else {
    /* En caso de que no hayan proporcionado ningún valor correcto */
    alert("Debe proporcionar algún valor a convertir");
    return;
  }
  document.f1.res.value = resultado;
}

</script>



<form name="f1">
  Grados: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="grados" /><br/>
  Radianes: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="radianes" /><br/><br/>
  <input onclick="formulario_calculadora()" type="button" value="Convertir" /><br/><br/>
  Resultado: <input maxlength="5" size="5" name="res" />
</form>
```

Para terminar, unos consejos:

- Sangra adecuadamente el código. Así evitarás los problemas que has sufrido con los bloques de código.
- Aunque sea opcional, finaliza todas las instrucciones con un punto y coma (`;`). Evitarás sorpresas en situaciones en las que pueda provocar errores.
- No extiendas la funcionalidad de clases existentes. Crea las tuyas propias. Eso no solo evitará futuras colisiones (aunque sea poco probable), si no que cualquier persona que lea tu código sabrá dónde buscar la implementación del código que se está ejecutando.
- Deberías usar la función [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) para convertir la cadena almacenada en el campo de texto en un valor de coma flotante y gestionar cuándo devuelve un `NaN` para saber cuándo no es un valor correcto.

Comment: Gran respuesta. Dos apuntes: (1) La condición del if debería comparar con la cadena vacía '' y no con null para funcionar correctamente; (2) Desconozco las convenciones de javascript pero en java los nombre de los métodos  se recomienda que comiencen por verbos. Ya que empleas una clase, quizas "convertirRadianesEnGrados" sea algo largo pero queda más claro qué es lo que hace el método si ponemos eso en lugar de solo "grados".

Comment: Las convenciones o guías de estilo las fijan las guías de estilo de cada proyecto, no es una regla fija o estándar. En javascript, por ejemplo, el uso del punto y coma al final es requerido en la guía de estilo de [google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-semicolons-are-required), pero están prohibidas en el proyecto [npm](https://doc.codingdict.com/npm-ref/misc/coding-style.html#semicolons). Hay muchísimos ejemplos más en los que no quiero entrar, pero el denominador común de casi todas las guías es llevar un buen sangrado del código, entre otros.

Comment: Por ultimo, sería casi mejor hacer una conversión a coma flotante con [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) y gestionar cuándo devuelve un `NaN`, en vez de delegar el trabajo a una conversión de cadenas. Quizá sea demasiado prematuro explicarle estas cosas al OP, pero se podría modificar el código para mejorar ese aspecto.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, el código funciona muy bien.

Solo tengo una última pregunta, simplemente por curiosidad: ¿existe alguna función de JavaScript que permita la entrada y salida de expresiones matemáticas más complejas?

Aplicado a este código, lo que quiero decir es que permitan la entrada en radianes. O por ejemplo, en algún otro código que se pueda expresar un resultado en formato fraccionario...

Muchas gracias.

Comment: La comparación estaba mal, con un "bien visto" o similar hubiera bastado. Lo de las guías de estilo en cada proyecto y los puntos y comas, está muy bien pero yo no los he mencionado. En POO y particularmente en java los métodos comienzan por un verbo y así lleva décadas establecido y mi nombre propuesto es informativo como recomienda el Clean Code. Sigue siendo una buena respuesta.

Comment: Te di  a tu comentario, acepté tu sugerencia y la apliqué en la respuesta y, finalmente, centré mi respuesta a tu comentario en hacerte ver que esas convenciones no son una regla inamovible, solo son eso, recomendaciones. Agradezco mucho tus sugerencias, pero seguro que las agradece aún más el OP si le facilitas enlaces a las recomendaciones de nomenclatura o guías de estilo a las que has hecho referencia. Está empezando y le vendrá bien aprender buenas prácticas o sugerencias útiles desde el principio.

Comment: Quizás este último comentario es para el OP, yo no estoy muy interesado en los radianes ahora mismo. ;-P

Comment: Así es, me confundí al nombrar a la persona equivocada  voy a borrarlo y volver a redactarlo nombrando al OP. Gracias por avisar 

Comment: @Oriol , existen multitud de bibliotecas de código que podrían ayudarte a conseguir lo que deseas. Creo que podrías empezar echando un vistazo a [Math.js](https://mathjs.org/examples/index.html).